# How to get count of named parameters in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

Viz. 
ABC.ps1 has this

```
param(
[bool]$A= $False,
[bool]$B= $False,
[bool]$C= $False
)

$count=$Args.Count
Write-Host "$count"
```

If I call it as:
.\ABC.ps1 $True $True $True
It should display 3.

This is just a guess, but $Args.Count is always zero, possibly because it Args doesn't hold/count named arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of named parameters can be gotten from $psboundparameters

```
&{param(
[bool]$A= $False,
[bool]$B= $False,
[bool]$C= $False
)
$psboundparameters | ft auto
$psboundparameters.count
} $true $true $true

Key Value
--- -----
A    True
B    True
C    True


3
```

$arg will indeed contain only the unbound parameters.

Comment: $psboundparameters.count is the thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$args will hold the count of values that exceeds the named parameters count (unbound parameters). If you have three named parameters and you send five arguments, $args.count will output 2.

Keep in mind that if the CmdletBinding attribute is present, no remaining arguments are allowed and you'll get an error:

```
function test
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param($a,$b,$c)
    $a,$b,$c    
}

test a b c d

test: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'd'.
```

To allow remaining arguments you will have use the ValueFromRemainingArguments parameter attribute. Now all unbound arguments will accumulate in $c:

```
function test
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param($a,$b,[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$c)
    "`$a=$a"
    "`$b=$b"
    "`$c=$c"    
}

test a b c d

$a=a
$b=b
$c=c d
```

Answer (score 2):

Named Param are bind in `$psboundparameters.count` any other additional arguments are bind in `$args.count` the total arguments passed is `($psboundparameters.count + $args.count).`

Test it:

```
param(
[bool]$A,
[bool]$B,
[bool]$C
)

$count=$Args.Count
Write-Host "$a - $b - $c - $($args[0]) - $count"

$psboundparameters.count

$args.count
```

call it `.\abc.ps1 $true $true $true $false`

Comment: $psboundparameters.count is the thing I was looking for. Thanks.